# What Canon lens, besides my 50mm f/1.8, should I get for my first wedding shoot?

Tags: lens, canon, wedding

I am shooting my first wedding in September and I have a Canon rebel t3i with a 50 mm 1.8 and I am trying to find a good lens under $900 dollars for the wedding so I am not stuck with just one lens. Any suggestions on what lens I should get next? I had looked into the 17-55mm 2.8? Is that any good?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend **not buying** a lens for this wedding (after all, what's more important, using this as an opportunity to build you kit, or ensuring you're delivering a good product to your first customer?), and spending part of that money on **renting another identical body**, along with one or two lenses for the wedding.

Being stuck with a single lens is not as bad as missing a shot because you're swapping lenses. Plus, if your body craps out (batteries, breaks, etc.), you have another body.

Which lenses? That's been asked many times here. See:

- [What Canon lenses do you suggest for wedding photography on a tight budget?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/10209/11924)
- [Will a prime lens help me get better portraits at a wedding?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/17830/11924)
- [Which one wide-medium lens to buy as the main lens for an outdoor wedding?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14348/11924)
- [Which one wide-medium canon lens is best for an indoor/outdoor wedding?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/33709/11924)
- [Which Canon 70-200mm f/2.8 is better for wedding photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/29561/11924)
- [Which Canon lens should I get for portraits/weddings?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/64858/11924)

For other beginning wedding shooting, see also:

- [Tips for photographing a wedding](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4922/11924)
- [How do I prepare best for my first wedding photography event?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/29723/11924)

And also search the [wedding](/questions/tagged/wedding) tag.

Comment: Definitely rent the same body with a lens. Shouldn't cost more than $100 and gives all the benefits outlined above. You have a fast 50mm now you need something fast (but not necessarily as fast as 1.8) with a decent range from wide(isn) for groups to tele so you can zoom in and isolate people in crowds. The 24-70 F2.8 sounds nice but also look at something like the Canon 24-105mm F4, as zoomed in F4 will give a nice shallow DOF.